# Using PNG tiles (QTiles) for publishing offline basemap

Tags: leaflet, gis, openstreetmap, qgis, geoserver

I need to add a map with some vector objects to my Django web-application to interact with object using Leaflet library. Now I have a vector map of a region, which was made with QGIS, and I made some tiles of a basemap using QTiles plugin. How can I publish this tiles to make a basemap. I'm afraid of freezes if I publish my map as it is (in vector format).

I was searching for any info about using Geoserver in this case, but there is nothing specific, but Geoserver has a plugin "ImageMosaic". Should I use it or there are easier ways to achive my goal?